# Load Report Failed On Server - Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report viewer page that displays a report perfectly well on my desktop development computer. The code I have used for this viewer page is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using LoyalitySystem;
using System.Configuration;
using HQ.DatabaseGateway;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using System.IO;

public partial class WebPages_DynamicReports_CrystalReportViewerPage : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string reportPath = Server.MapPath((string)Utils.GetSessionNavigator(this).GetDataFromCurrentPage(PageParams.Reports.Report));
        ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument();

        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(reportPath))
            {
                Response.Write("The specified report does not exist \n");
            }

            rep.Load(reportPath);
            LoadReport(rep);
            this.CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
            this.CrystalReportViewer1.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = false;
            this.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private bool LoadReport(ReportDocument doc)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo crTableLogonInfo;
        Sections crSections;
        Database crDatabase;
        Tables crTables;
        ReportDocument crSubreportDocument;
        ReportObjects crReportObjects;
        SubreportObject crSubreportObject;

        try
        {
            ConnectionInfo con = new ConnectionInfo();
            con.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbsource"];
            con.DatabaseName = Utils.GetSessionNavigator(this).UserData.DatabaseName;
            con.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uid"];
            con.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwd"];
            crDatabase = doc.Database;
            crTables = crDatabase.Tables;

            //loop through all the tables and pass in the connection info
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
            {
                crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = con;
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
            }

            // set the crSections object to the current report's sections
            crSections = doc.ReportDefinition.Sections;

            // loop through all the sections to find all the report objects
            foreach (Section crSection in crSections)
            {
                crReportObjects = crSection.ReportObjects;
                // loop through all the report objects to find all the subreports
                foreach (ReportObject crReportObject in crReportObjects)
                {
                    if (crReportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                    {
                        crSubreportObject = (SubreportObject)crReportObject;

                        // open the subreport object
                        crSubreportDocument = crSubreportObject.OpenSubreport(crSubreportObject.SubreportName);

                        // set the database and tables objects to work with the subreport
                        crDatabase = crSubreportDocument.Database;
                        crTables = crDatabase.Tables;

                        // loop through all the tables in the subreport and 
                        // set up the connection info and apply it to the tables
                        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
                        {
                            crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                            crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = con;
                            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

As previously stated, this works fine when locally hosting my application, but on the production server I am getting Load Report Failed on every report that I run, and from my check to see if the file exists, I can see that the requested file is being found.

My .aspx markup is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CrystalReportViewerPage.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="WebPages_DynamicReports_CrystalReportViewerPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="cr" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>CrystalReportViewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <cr:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" HasCrystalLogo="False" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My web.config file contains:

```
    <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
        <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
            <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>

        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".rpt" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.Compilation.RptBuildProvider, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        </buildProviders>
```

And I have installed both `CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_2` and `CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_2` redistributables on my Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter server at different times and both have failed to resolve the issue. The application connects to an Amazon RDS SQL Server Instance, being on an Amazon EC2 instance itself.

I've searched over the internet for some time to find the solution for this issue but apparently the Load Report Failed message is quite broad in its meaning, so I hope that I can solve this problem with help towards this particular instance of the issue.

I have been stuck with this issue for over a week now so I would be grateful if any help can be offered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message usually shows that the report is not available using the provided path. If runtime is not installed you will receive different message.In your case everything is installed correctly but the report is not available in reportPath  + rpName. You can debug and check were reportPath + rpName is pointing and if the report is really there. Try to use Path.Combine( reportPath , rpName) - it will add \ if necessary. Also check if IIS has permission to access the reports in reportPath folder.

Comment: I'm using string reportPath = Server.MapPath("../DynamicReports/"); as my report path, debugging shows it points towards the report, but on the server I'm still getting this issue, is my path wrong? Do I have to change permissions for IIS_IUSRS to view the contents of the folder on the server?

Comment: I don't know . My guess is that if the path is correct the issue is with the permissions. Keep in mind also that when you a loading the report, depending on the options, it may create a temp file and load the report from the temp file . So you need to make sure that the user has pemissions for the temp folder ( read\write)

Comment: It turns out that the issue was a mix of permissions on the Reports folder (As Lan suggested) and a bug that can arise when publishing an ASP.Net application with embedded reports, leading to the report being compressed down to 1KB in size. Replacing the reports with a copy from my development computer resolved the issue. Thank you Lan for the effort you put in to resolve the problem.